# How to subsample a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have `dfi`= (i is the index)

```
i     a
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
7     7
8     8
9     9
```

and `dfj`= (j is the index)

```
j     b
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
```

I want to add an `a` column to `dfj` such that the output would be `dfi` subsampled by a factor of 2

```
j     b     a
0     0     0
1     1     2
2     2     4
3     3     6
4     4     8
```

---

My attempt:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
dfj["a"] = dfi.loc[idx[::2]]
```

This fails because `dfi.loc[idx[::2]]` returns indices that don't fit for `dfj`. Looks like I need to divide the index, or do another workaround.

What's the correct syntax for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dfi.iloc[::2]` or `dfi.loc[idx[::2]]` has different indexes than `dfj`, while assignment will align the indexes for you. You can pass the values instead:

```
dfj['a'] = dfi['a'].iloc[::2].values
```

Output:

```
   b  a
j      
0  0  0
1  1  2
2  2  4
3  3  6
4  4  8
```